# Powerquery transform for grouping by State

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a report that I'm given monthly that I'm hoping to clean up and automate using Powerquery. It is a summary of sales performance, grouped by store location, so that every four or five rows, there is a row that's just displaying city name, like so:

Products:
Dallas
Apples|3,212
Oranges|1,253
Bananas|4,394
Seattle
Apples|598
Oranges|3,409
Bananas|3,120
Grapes|2,341

How would I be able to add a column, and assign the city value to that column for each of those respective rows?

I have tried transposing operations in powerquery, but have not yet figured out if that's possible, or the best method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you start from this:

[image]

Then you can add a custom column:

[image]

Then use fill-down on the new column:

[image]

Which will give you this:

[image]

Finally you can filter out the rows with null sales:

[image]

To get:

[image]

Comment: That's awesome @flexyourdata and I think will work perfectly, thanks for the quick response! Quick follow up, I have a similar report elsewhere, but that is formatted WITH the total amount for the city location as well; is there a way to still accomplish in the event you can't rely on the amount to be null?

Comment: In that case I would say you'd need a way to distinguish between a city and a product. Either a list of valid city names, or a list of unique product names, such that you can check each row for existence (or not) in said list and populate the city column accordingly. If you have such a list, post a new question and I (or someone else) can show you how to do the existence check I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense at a high level. I will post a follow up question, then. Much appreciated.