# Powerquery adding column based on a store location

Tags: excel, powerquery

From a previous question, I'm trying to figure out how to add a new column based on location, when the adjacent cell DOES have a total amount for that location (not null).

[Powerquery transform for grouping by State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77719235/powerquery-transform-for-grouping-by-state)

For location names such as: Dallas, Seattle, New York, DC, and Des Moines.
So, the source table would look like:

|  Dallas|4,000|
|Apples|1,000|
|Grapes|2,000|
|Bananas|1,000|
|  Seattle|5,000|
|Pears|500|
|Apples|2000|
|Bananas|2,500|
|  New York|8,000|
|Apples|4,000|
|Bananas|2,000|
|Grapes|1,000|
|Oranges|1,000|

Blockquote

Comment: What does your expected result look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your city names start with a space, then the answer from @horseyride is simplest.

If they don't start with a space, then as mentioned in my answer to your other question, you can use a list of known cities or known products to separate them.

Suppose you start with this:

[image]

Load both tables into Power Query:

[image]

Then in your Sales query, you can add a custom column that checks whether a value in the Product column of the Sales table exists in the Location column of the Locations table.

[image]

After that, you can use Fill-down as previously (right-click the city column, Fill>Down):

[image]

You can then choose to filter out the city aggregates where [Product] = [City] if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If your locations actually start with a space like in your question, you can use

```
= if Text.Start([Products],1)=" " then [Products] else null
```

Otherwise, I think you would need to know a list of potential non-location products in advance